# Material Components theme renders TextButton incorrectly

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-theme, material-components

After following the instructions at [getting-started](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) to update our Android app to inherit from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light`, text only buttons are being rendered incorrectly.

In the notes, the docs state:

```
Note: Using a Material Components theme enables a custom view inflater 
which replaces default components with their Material counterparts. 
Currently, this only replaces <Button> XML components with 
<MaterialButton>.
```

Is there a way to disable the custom view inflatar or fix the issue with buttons?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by 'incorrectly'?

Comment: If you look at the example above, those buttons should look like Text buttons

Answer (score 0):

Custom inflater replaces only names without qualifiers, so you can just use the full qualified name whenever you need a specific view to be used. In your case replace `<Button>` with `<android.widget.Button>` in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Dialog` or `AppCompatDialog`? If you use `AppCompatDialog` I think it should have the correct style by default. Otherwise you should ensure that the dialog is using this style: `@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog` or a style that sets 
`buttonBarButtonStyle` to `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog`.